# How can I add Rinkeby in Metamask?

Tags: metamask, testing, rinkeby, cpp-ethereum, chainid

I have a problem: I can't add Rinkeby Test Network in Metamask. First, I tried to add it from settings -> show test networks(on) and it doesn't work. Then I tried to add it manually and I created an Infura account where I did a project(Network: Web3 API). After this, I added manually the following details (look in the second picture) and also it doesn't work. How can I fix this problem?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rinkeby is deprecated and it's not supported any more.
recomended test network to use is `Goerli` right now if you can't see it in your metamask make sure you turned on `show test networks` in settings -> advanced section